# Is "text" an acceptable past tense?

Tags: tenses

Please clarify the correct tense of the word *text.*

Every time I hear somebody say "I text my friend," or "I checked
my texts' " it makes me cringe.  I understand and use the correct tense, but if I point it out to others when they do not, a debate ensues.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. When you write *tense*, do you mean *sense*? The tense of a verb (only verbs have tenses, and in your second example *text* is not a verb) is about whether the action takes place in the past, present or future. The sense of a word is its meaning.

Comment: Are you saying that they use "text" as the past tense of the verb _to text_, rather than "texted"?  In your second example, what problem do you have with "checking my texts"?  Do you wish they had said "text messages"? I'm afraid that's too long of a phrase for people who think in <160 char thoughts. I have a hard enough time convincing people that _email_ is a non-count noun, and therefore does not take the plural form _emails_  (sound of chalk screeching on blackboard!!)

Answer (score 2):

*Text* can be a noun, meaning "SMS message". A statement "I checked my texts" is perfectly fine. Even if you're not talking SMS, a *text* can be a literary excerpt or a complete volume, and "I checked my texts" means "I checked the reference works I cited".

*Text* can be a verb, meaning "send an SMS message". A statement "I text my friend" is a bit odd as present tense (when "I am texting" would usually be preferred), and idiosyncratic as a past-tense form.

However, AAVE has a form *axed* for *asked*. There may be a link made between the past-tense sound of *axed* and the similar-sounding word *text* which is then taken as an acceptable past-tense form rather than the mass of phonemes of *texted*. Even without this possible link, a conversational "I text her that" is easier to say than "I texted her that": the *-ed* suffix is effectively elided.

Answer (score 0):

If you're upset about *text* instead of *text message* then I'd say you need to get with the times... Surely you don't still say *cellular telephone*?

But if you're asking about saying something like "I text him yesterday" (it's not clear to me from your question) then while I'm not familiar with this formation *specifically*, it's a common storytelling thing to put all verbs in present tense ("She told me not to text him, but I'm mad, so I go and text him anyway!")

I think using the present form of 'text' to refer to a past action will be understood by most people, and I really doubt there's need to get upset over it... There's enough to be upset about in this world without making new battles!